# Why does the differential $f_{*,p}$ equals $g_{*,p}$ at every point $p\in N$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Hi i am reading An introduction to manifolds by Loring and have 1 doubt in the proof of lemma 9.7. It is written that

> the differential $f_{*,p}$ equals $g_{*,p}$ at every point $p\in N$

My question is how do we know that the the differential $f_{*,p}$ equals $g_{*,p}$ at every point $p\in N$? For reference i am attaching the screenshot of proof where i have highlighted the part in which this is mentioned.

> **Lemma 9.7.** Let $g:N\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a $C^\infty$ function. A regular level set $g^{-1}(c)$ of level $c$ of the function $g$ is the regular zero set $f^{-1}(0)$ of the function $f=g-c$.
>
> *Proof.* For any $p\in N$,
> $$g(p)=c\Longleftrightarrow f(p)=g(p)-c=0.$$
> Hence, $g^{-1}(c)=f^{-1}(0)$. Call this set $S$. Because the differential $f_{*,p}$ equals $g_{*,p}$ at every point $p\in N$, the functions $f$ and $g$ have exactly the same critical ponits. Since $g$ has no critical points in $S$, neither does $f$. $\qquad\square$

Comment: f and g differ by a constant. I'm sure in the one-variable case you'd agred two functions which differ by a constant have the same derivative; it's the same situation here (just unwind the definitions of push forward/differential carefully to see this)

Comment: @peek-a-boo yeah i was trying to do that before already but couldn't succeed .This is what i tried. The definition of the differential is as follows:$(F_\*(X_p))k=X_{p}(k\circ F)$, where $k$ is the representative germ and $F$ is the function whose differential has to be taken If i replace $F$ by $f$ as in our case then we get:$(f_{\*}X_p)k=X_{p}(k\circ f)=X_{p}(k\circ g-c)=X_{p}(k\circ g) - X_{p}(k\circ c)$. Is this correct? Will the second term evaluate to 0 here so that we get $f_{*,p}=g_{*,p}$?

Comment: Remember that the codomain of $g$ and $f$ is $\Bbb R$. Thus $X_p$ is just some multiple of $\frac d{dt}$. You cannot say that $k(g - c) = kg - kc$ because $k$ need not be linear. And technically, for a point $p \in N$, germs at $g(p)$ and $g(p) - c$ are not the same objects (though they are naturally isomorphic). But since we are in $\Bbb R$ now, you can apply the chain rule.

Comment: @PaulSinclair The chain rule as i applied or something differently? Also note that c is just a constant real number in the equation $X_{p}(k\circ c)$ .So how should i go about it? Can you write an answer explaining and answering the complete thing so that i can mark it as correct answer and understand it as well . I mean using the definition of the differential. Thanks.

Comment: You wrote "$X_p(k \circ f) = X_p(k\circ g - c) = X_p(k\circ g) - X_(k\circ c)$". But that is not correct. You assumed that $k$ acts linearly. It does not. What it should be is $X_p(k\circ f) = X_p(k\circ(g - c))$, and that is where it stops, because there is no reason that $k\circ(g-c) = (k\circ g) - (k\circ c)$. It doesn't matter if $c$ is constant or not. $k$ is *not linear*. And further $k$ is a germ at $f(p) = g(p) - c$. It is not a germ at $g(p)$  nor at $c$, so neither expression $k \circ g$ nor $k \circ c$ is definable.

Comment: Yeah that i understand the first time you said it. I am saying then what other option do we have? Now, how will we show that the differential $f_{*,q}$ and $g_{*,q}$ are equal at every point?

Comment: Jason Liam, i think you should have tagged @PaulSinclair

Comment: @PaulSinclair anyhoo so how do we get the equality of the differentials? I've thought about this and i kinda think of something like $(f=g-c)_{*,p} = g_{*,p} - c_{*,p}$ and then $c_{*,p} = 0$, but then what is this mysterious operator $(\cdot)_{*,p}$ ? Sounds like we're gonna do some bundle stuff like $(\cdot)_{*,\cdot}: C^{\infty}N \to T^{dual}N$ or maybe do like $f_{*,p}(X_p)=(df)_pX_p \frac{d}{dt}|_{f(p)}$ but in either case we're using section 17 stuff to answer a question for section 9

Answer (score 3):

Note that $f_{\ast,p}$ is a map $T_pN\rightarrow T_{f(p)}\mathbb{R}$, whereas $g_{\ast,p}$ is a map $T_pN\rightarrow T_{g(p)}\mathbb{R}$. So, in a strict sense, these are not equal, because they do not even have the same codomain. In particular, trying to calculate this by definition as you did is doomed to fail. However, there are natural identifications $T_{f(p)}\mathbb{R}\cong\mathbb{R}\cong T_{g(p)}\mathbb{R}$ (which, I'm sure, Tu has introduced before this point) under which the maps in fact become equal.

I believe a conceptual approach clarifies best why this is true. Let $a\colon\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R},\,x\mapsto x-c$ be the auxiliary "subtraction by $c$" map. Then, $f=a\circ g$ by definition, whence $f_{\ast,p}=(a\circ g)_{\ast,p}=a_{\ast,g(p)}\circ g_{\ast,p}$ by the chain rule. However, $a_{\ast,g(p)}$ is an isomorphism, since $a$ is a diffeomorphism. This already implies that $f_{\ast,p}$ is surjective iff $g_{\ast,p}$ is surjective, so that the critical points of $f$ and $g$ are the same. Furthermore, this also lets us see that these maps are the same under the given identifications, since they identify the abstract derivative with the classical derivative from analysis and $a^{\prime}(g(p))=1$.

Comment: +1 I suspect Tu may have defined differentials of functions (i.e., into $\Bbb R$) with the natural identification of $T_p\Bbb R$ with $\Bbb R$ already built in. It is not an uncommon practice.

Comment: thanks Thorgott and @PaulSinclair ! i'll analyse a little more later before awarding the bounty (i'm not OP btw, but i am the bounty offeror)

Comment: Thorgott and @PaulSinclair ah so it's like saying that differential of inclusion from open subset $U$ of $M$ is identity in the sense that $T_pU$ 'equals' $T_pM$?

Comment: Thorgott and @PaulSinclair in particular the 'identity' here is $a_{*,g(p)}$ viewed as like $a_{*,g(p)}: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ ?

Comment: Note: can't award bounty yet. need to wait 9 hrs